# dpkg: is it ipossible to split ${shlibs:Depends}?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I am building a project consisting of the
main binary and a number of .so plugins.
Every .so plugin is linked to a particular
library, and they all export the "generic"
API to the main binary, which dlopen()'s
them.

For example, if the basic linux distro
has 10+ different libs for sound output,
I will have 10 .so plugins for sound output,
providing the same API to the main binary,
so it doesn't matter if 9 of them will fail
to dlopen() because their lib is not installed:
successfully dlopen()'ing just 1 would be enough.
That's why I put ${shlibs:Depends} to 'Recommends:'
rather than to 'Depends:'.

Unfortunately this
puts also the deps for the main binary to
'Recommends:', which is not what I actually want.
Is there any way to split ${shlibs:Depends}
into parts? It would help if I could split
it by the binary name, say,
${shlibs:Depends(main_binary)}, ${shlibs:Depends(solib1.so)}
etc. But splitting by patterns can work too.

So is there any way of splitting such variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by specifying the appropriate arguments to `dpkg-shlibdeps`; in your case, something like

```
dpkg-shlibdeps -dDepends -emain_binary \
               -dRecommends -esolib1.so -esolib2.so ...
```

Then use `${shlibs:Depends}` and `${shlibs:Recommends}` in the appropriate locations.

If you’re using `dh` overrides, use

```
override_dh_shlibdeps:
        dpkg-shlibdeps ...
```

You’ll find a (somewhat more complex) example of this in [the Wine package](https://salsa.debian.org/wine-team/wine/-/blob/fe3452cc312b8202010652eca34cec9ef4921336/debian/rules#L224). That runs `dh_shlibdeps` again because its `dpkg-shlibdeps` override only handles one package.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Stephen Kitt's answer, I did the following override:

```
override_dh_shlibdeps:
    dh_shlibdeps -X.so
    dh_shlibdeps -- -dRecommends -pshlibs-
```

The first one creates ${shlibs:Depends} for main binary
excluding .so plugin files, and the second one creates
${shlibs-:Recommends}.

Note that I had to mangle the var prefix to "shlibs-" so
that the second invocation of dpkg-shlibdeps to not
overwrite the results of the first invocation. It appears
that just specifying new suffix with -d is not enough to
prevent the overwrite: before generating ${shlibs:Recommends}
it would for some reason remove all ${shlibs:*}. But mangling
the prefix with -p fixes the problem.